# How to fix 'CSRF verification failed' using requests module

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using python requests library and I'm trying to login to https://www.udemy.com/join/login-popup/, the problem is when I use the following header:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36'}
```

it returns `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted`.

When I change it to:

```
headers = {'Referer': url}
```

it returns `Please verify that you are a human`.

any suggestions?

**My code:**

```
import requests


with requests.session() as s:
    url = 'https://www.udemy.com/join/login-popup/'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                             'Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36'}
    request = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    cookies = dict(cookies=request.cookies)
    csrf = request.cookies['csrftoken']
    data_login = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf, 'locale': 'en_US', 'email': 'myemail',
                  'password': 'maypassword'}
    request = s.post(url, data=data_login, headers={'Referer': url}, cookies=cookies['cookies'])
    print(request.content)
```

Comment: Since you're using the same `Session` object, you shouldn't need to manage cookies manually at all.

Comment: According to https://blogs.sap.com/2014/07/11/issues-with-csrf-token-and-how-to-solve-them/, you probably need to add CSRF related information to your headers. Might be more than 1 header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your current code:

1. The header you are using is missing a few things
2. The value that you are passing for `csrfmiddlewaretoken` isn't correct
3. As you're using `requests.session()` you shouldn't include cookies manually *(in this case)*

Try this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with requests.session() as s:
    url = 'https://www.udemy.com/join/login-popup/'
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0", "Referer": "https://www.udemy.com/join/login-popup/", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"}

    request = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "lxml")
    csrf = soup.find("input",{"name":"csrfmiddlewaretoken"})["value"]

    data_login = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf, 'locale': 'en_US', 'email': 'myemail@test.com','password': 'maypassword'}
    request = s.post(url, data=data_login, headers=headers)
    print(request.content)
```

*(PS: I'm using the [Beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library in order to find the value of   `csrfmiddlewaretoken`)*

Hope this helps